# Android XML Layout Custom Attribute Values Dropdown

Tags: android, android-xml

I am looking for a way that there will be dropdown of available value inside custom attribute in Android XML, just like below:

[image]

Here what I have done:

**attrs.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="font">
        <attr name="fontType" format="string" />
        <attr name="textSizeType" format="string" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Use it this way:

```
<com.MyTextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    font:fontType="regular"
    font:textSizeType="caption" />
```

That later the values of custom attributes will be interpreted inside MyTextView class.

Is there any way I can have dropdown of available values for custom attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Try defining your attribute as an enum:

```
<attr name="my_attr">
  <enum name="value1" value="1" />
  <enum name="value2" value="2" />
</attr>
```

From your screenshot, it looks like you are still using Eclipse.  I don't know that the Eclipse ADT plugin will make a dropdown out of your enum values, but you can try it and see.

Comment: Yes I am still using Eclipse. However, the font tag itself doesn't show dropdown for autocomplete when I finish typing `font:` and press `ctrl+space` to show the dropdown. Maybe I should try moving to Android Studio.

Comment: It may not work in Android Studio either, I haven't tried it.  I just know that the only way the IDE can make a dropdown is if it knows what all the legal values are for the attribute.